# Use a json decode array without foreach

Tags: php, json, date, foreach

I have a following json:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Peter","bday":"1990-10-10"},{"name":"Mark","bday":"1992-08-10"},{"name":"John","bday":"1993-08-09"},{"name":"John","bday":"2000-05-19"}]';
```

Are names and Birthdays. Is there any way to use a criteria to search birthdays without foreach?

For example, "all registry with birthdays after `1993-01-01`".

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, for example using `array_filter()`.

Comment: @JohnConde 
None. But I think that maybe there is a more efficient method, that I return the data according to some criterion, without my having to go through them all ...

Comment: I have a working example using array_filter() but I don't want to post it without seeing some sort of effort on your part first

Comment: What makes you think a foreach loop is slow or slower than other methods?

Comment: Also check out this interesting post on array_ vs loops http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/

Comment: @rs007 I'd like to see those same tests run with PHP 7. I wonder if it would be different?

Comment: @JohnConde I made an effort =D. I figure out now...

Comment: @rs007 I read the article... So... Loops are faster? Interesting....

Comment: @JohnConde I thought that use array functions are faster than loops... That's why I ask.

Comment: Also to @John Conde's point, I am not sure about perf in 7+ version, this article is from 2015,  just a good read I felt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with `array_filter` function

```
function greater_than($arr){
    $date = $arr['bday'];

    if(strtotime($date) > strtotime('1993-01-01')){
        return $date;
    }
}

$json = '[{"name":"Peter","bday":"1990-10-10"},{"name":"Mark","bday":"1992-08-10"},{"name":"John","bday":"1993-08-09"},{"name":"John","bday":"2000-05-19"}]';
$dec = json_decode($json,true);
print_r(array_filter($dec, "greater_than"));
```

Comment: But is this actually *better*?